# Ruby class method reference

Tags: ruby, reflection

In Ruby, we can easily reference a method and pass in a *callback*-like fashion in the same scope like this:

```
my_method = method(:method_name)
```

How would you reference a class method defined on another class?

So if I had:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
      def my_method
        // ... do stuff
      end
  end
end
```

How would I reference that method in a different class to use in a `method(...)` call?

Comment: It's a bit confusing that `my_method` is a variable at first and then a method name.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question with some thinking:

You don't need `method(...)` at all in this case.

Instead you can just use:

```
MyClass.public_method(:my_method)
```

Comment: _"Just use `public_method` instead of `method`"_ misses the point. The relevant part is that you have to provide an explicit receiver in order to search methods in another object.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. There are only instance methods. What we call a "class method", is actually just a singleton method of an object that happens to be a class.

Wait, did I just say "singleton method"? Actually, I lied. There are no singleton methods either. What we call a "singleton method" is actually just an instance method of a singleton class.

So, considering that there are only instance methods anyway, and you already know how to reference instance methods, you already know the answer to your question. You were just taught badly, because someone told you that there is such a thing as a "class method", when in fact there isn't.

So, you have actually answered your own question in your question: the method you are looking for is `Object#method`.